# Why does this char* comparison function return -1 when the two input strings are the same? Language: C

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, string-comparison, function-definition

I made a function that is supposed to help me order strings in alphabetical order: it should return -1 if the first string comes before the second one, 0 if they are the same string and 1 if the first string comes after the second one. This is the code:

`

```
int testString(char* a, char* b){
    int i = 0;
    
    while(a[i] != EOF && b[i] != EOF){
        if(a[i] > b[i]){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            if(a[i] < b[i]){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(a[i] == EOF && b[i]!=EOF){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        if(a[i] != EOF && b[i] == EOF){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            if(a[i] == EOF && b[i] == EOF){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                printf("Problem in the string comparison\n");
                return -2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

So: it does a while cycle as long as there are characters in the string and, if one string is the same as the other, but longer, it should return 1, -1 in the very opposite case and 0 if they are the very same, so same length. Though, this returns -1 with the very same strings and i don't get why.

I tried using it to order an array of structs of which one element was of type char* and it does work (because the sorting algorithm is a quick sort, and the one i made doesn't make a distinction between less than and equal to, during the sorting). I later printed out the strings of the array of structs and they were indeed ordered.
Problem is that the testing (which used this same function) to see whether or not they were in order told me that they weren't, as it returned -1 instead of 0, when the strings were the same, so the anti-alphabetical order wasn't respected. Now i looked at the function, but it looks OK and i don't get what's wrong with it

Comment: You should compare to `0`, not to `EOF`. Strings end with `0`, files end with `EOF`.

Comment: `EOF` is not a `char`

Comment: @dimich The common value of `EOF` is -1 and is savable in a `char`, without value change, when it is _signed_.  This is common.

Comment: Ugo Flickerman, update is a new question and rolled back.  Poor etiquette to shift the question after answers arrive.  As needed, post a new question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Type of decimal constant without suffixes is first of `int`, `long` or `long long` which can hold it.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Files don't end with `EOF`. `EOF` value just indicates that a function reached end of file.

Comment: `strcmp` is exactly this function?

Answer (score 4):

From the C Standard (7.21 Input/output <stdio.h>)

> **EOF** which expands to an integer constant expression, **with type int and
> a negative value**, that is returned by several functions to
> indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

Usually this macro is expanded to `-1`.

But you need to compare strings. Strings are sequences of characters that ended with the terminating zero character `'\0'`

So this while loop

```
while(a[i] != EOF && b[i] != EOF){
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

Also this else statement

```
        else{
            printf("Problem in the string comparison\n");
            return -2;
        }
```

will never get the control. So it is redundant.

And introducing the variable `i` of the type `int`

```
int i = 0;
```

is also redundant.

Your function can look the following way

```
int testString( const char *a, const char *b )
{
    while ( *a != '\0' && *a == *b )
    {
        ++a;
        ++b;
    }

    return ( *( unsigned char * )b < *( unsigned char * )a ) - 
           ( *( unsigned char * )a < *( unsigned char * )b );
}
```

Comment: Only for the pedantic: Consider `*( unsigned char *)b` instead of `( unsigned char )*b`.  That is the correct functionality and makes a difference with non-2's complement.  IAC, a non-issue with C2x.

Comment: or more cleanly with `int testString( const char *a, const char *b ) { const unsigned char *ua = a; const unsigned char *ub = b; ...`. and use `ua`, `ub`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while(a[i] != EOF && b[i] != EOF){
> ```

The string terminator is `0`, not `EOF`.  Change that to

```
while (a[i] != 0 && b[i] != 0 )
```

or just

```
while (a[i] && b[i])
```

Do the same in the remainder of your code where you're comparing against `a[i]` and `b[i]` against `EOF`.

There is no `EOF` character as such - `EOF` is the value returned by input functions if they detect an end-of-file condition on a stream.